# How to debug before execution stops at nullpointerexception, of a pre-compiled jar file?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

I would like to debug why an object return null from this line

```
debug_log = LoggingConfigFileLoader.getLogFilePaths().get("debug.log");
```

At here: https://github.com/UniversalMediaServer/UniversalMediaServer/blob/master/src/main/java/net/pms/PMS.java#L356

I hope to know what java execution is happening *before* the exception take place. Unfortunately the `.jar` is from a big project and may be difficult to build. Especially for me, who knows nothing java. This is on openjdk7, (which the java developer use too). However the code was never before run on FreeBSD.

In the end, I would like to find the true reason / underlying cause for this unhandled exception:

```
ums4 UMS/ root~# /usr/local/openjdk7/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -classpath /usr/local/share/universal-media-server/ums.jar net.pms.PMS
 18:18:12.424 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.c.ConfigurationUtils - ConfigurationUtils.locate(): base is null, name is /root/.config/UMS/UMS.conf
 18:18:12.430 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.c.DefaultFileSystem - Could not locate file /root/.config/UMS/UMS.conf at null: no protocol: /root/.config/UMS/UMS.conf
 18:18:12.431 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.c.ConfigurationUtils - Loading configuration from the absolute path /root/.config/UMS/UMS.conf
 18:18:12.431 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.c.PropertiesConfiguration - Base path set to file:///root/.config/UMS/UMS.conf
 18:18:12.463 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.c.PropertiesConfiguration - FileName set to UMS.conf
 18:18:12.464 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.c.PropertiesConfiguration - Base path set to /root/.config/UMS
 18:18:12.480 [main] DEBUG n.p.c.ConfigurationReader - Reading cred.path: default: "", current: "/root/.config/UMS/UMS.cred"
 18:18:12.498 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - Starting Universal Media Server 4.0.0-a1
 18:18:12.499 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - Based on PS3 Media Server by shagrath, copyright 2008-2014
 18:18:12.499 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - http://www.universalmediaserver.com
 18:18:12.499 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - 
 18:18:12.499 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - Build: 38318285b (2014-06-02)
 18:18:12.499 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - Java: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_60 64-bit by Oracle Corporation
 18:18:12.500 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - OS: FreeBSD 64-bit 9.2-RELEASE-p3
 18:18:12.500 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - Encoding: US-ASCII
 18:18:12.522 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - Memory: 313 MB
 18:18:12.522 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - Language: en
 18:18:12.522 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - 
 18:18:12.523 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - Working directory: /var/db/universal-media-server/.config/UMS
 18:18:12.525 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - Temp directory: /tmp/universalmediaserver
 18:18:12.525 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - Logging config file: internal defaults
 18:18:12.526 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - 
 18:18:12.526 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - Profile directory: /root/.config/UMS
 18:18:12.527 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - Profile directory permissions: rw
 18:18:12.527 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - Profile path: /root/.config/UMS/UMS.conf
 18:18:12.527 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - Profile permissions: rw
 18:18:12.527 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - Profile name: ums4
 18:18:12.528 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - 
 18:18:12.528 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - Web conf path: /root/.config/UMS/WEB.conf
 18:18:12.528 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - Web conf permissions: file not found
 18:18:12.528 [main] INFO  net.pms.PMS - 
 18:18:12.540 [main] ERROR net.pms.PMS - A serious error occurred during PMS init
 java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at net.pms.newgui.DbgPacker.<init>(DbgPacker.java:40) ~[ums.jar:4.0.0-a1]
    at net.pms.PMS.displayBanner(PMS.java:357) [ums.jar:4.0.0-a1]
    at net.pms.PMS.init(PMS.java:509) [ums.jar:4.0.0-a1]
    at net.pms.PMS.createInstance(PMS.java:1038) [ums.jar:4.0.0-a1]
    at net.pms.PMS.main(PMS.java:1138) [ums.jar:4.0.0-a1]
```

Comment: *I hope to know what java execution is happening before the exception take place?*. The stack trace gives you a pretty good idea. You will need the source code to dive into further depths.. Do you have the source code with you?

Comment: The NPE is thrown on this line: https://github.com/UniversalMediaServer/UniversalMediaServer/blob/master/src/main/java/net/pms/newgui/DbgPacker.java#L40

Comment: FYI we found a way to avoid hitting the exception. By starting the program in same folder as where the `UMS.jar` file exist. So `CWD=/usr/local/share/universal-media-server`. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to load the project into IDE and set up "break on exception" breakpoint (e.g. in Eclipse it's in "Run -> Add Java Exception Breakpoint...").

But I believe that this method is suitable only for relatively small projects. For example yesterday I's tired of waiting while a guava's Preconditions check breaks the execution of a long batch processing and I added some logging and re-ran the process w/o debugger. So YMMV.